# How to retrieve every single element from a tree?

Tags: c++

I been stuck here for a few days. Could anyone take a look at the toString method in the Row class, how can I retrieve every point from a tree of points and get the char value from the point? I know in vector or array we can probably use a for loop and do something like find(points[i]), but I really have no clue here.

```
   **std::string toString() const
   {
      string s;
      for(int i = 0; i != points.size(); i++)
      {
         //Maybe use points.find(???) here to retrieve the point
         s.push_back(point.getType()); //Just for demonstration, this does not work
         return s;

      }
   }**
};
```

So I cannot modify the binNode binTree class. And I cannot have the print method in the Point class, because the print() method print every element in a new line. But we have to retrieve the char value from every point, and attach all char value of all point into a String.
Thank you so much for giving me a hint!

Comment: `And I cannot have the print method in the Point class` - there is no `print` method in `Point` class?

Comment: can you add your main function also? can you modify `Point` or `Row` classes? (i assume `binNode` and `binTree` are given as input to your problem, right?)

Comment: Hi NirMH. Thank you for your reply. I have added the main method, and there is actually a Square class. So the first step I will need to do is to read a square that made up with rows of char from a file, and print the square to the screen.

Comment: `-1` for "debug that wall of code for me".

Comment: Sorry if it is disturbing. I have been trying to modify the code for many times to try to work it out myself. And it is not buggy actually. I am just trying to get hint because my knowledge is limited. I've been using c++ for only a few months. But again, I will work on it by myself

Answer (score 1):

The `binNode` template doesn't really support that sort of usage because it doesn't expose it's children. Nor does it supply an `iterator`. That makes it impossible to traverse the tree in code that is outside the class. The children are not even visible to subclasses so you can't extend it that way.

You could get hacky and specialize the `binNode` template for `Point` and force it to emit output into a global `string`:

```
std::string output; // a global

template <>
class binNode<Point> {
    void print() const {
        if (left != NULL) left->print();
        output += nodeData.getType();
        if (right != NULL) right->print();
    }
};

// in some function
output.clear(); // remember to clear previous output
points.print(); // the string now has the output from `print`
```

This will of course not work if you have multiple threads calling `print` even on separate `bintree`s.

To properly implement such functionality, your only option is to modify `bintree` and `binNode`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is why I feel it is difficult to implement this with tree and we cannot modify the tree and node classes : (

Comment: @user3226289, not only difficult, but also impossible (except for the hacky solution which is bad for many reasons).